# Checar se um elemento existe com switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch

Olá, como faço para fazer uma checagem e verificar se determinado elemento existe usando switch?
 Para ser mais especifico, estou tentando usar este código:

```
var forumversion = function()
{
    invision = jQuery('#ipbwrapper').length ? "invision" : "error";
    phpbb2   = jQuery('.bodyline').length ? "phpbb2" : "error";
    phpbb3   = jQuery('#wrap').length ? "phpbb3" : "error";
    punbb    = jQuery('#pun-intro').length ? "punbb" : "error";
}
switch( forumversion )
{
            case invision: "Invision";
                break;

            case phpbb2: "phpBB2";
                break;

            case phpbb3: "phpBB3";
                break;

            case punbb: "punbb";
                break;

            default: "Erro ao identificar a versão do fórum"
}
```

Neste caso quero checar qual a versão de determinados fóruns.. Para fazer isso eu checo se determinados elementos específicos de cada versão existem (dentro da var forumversion estão os elementos..)..
 Sou novo com switch ainda, onde eu poderia estar errando?

Comment: Não consegui compreender bem o objetivo, mas, no seu caso não seria melhor utilizar `if`?

Comment: Sim, com if eu sei como fazer.. Mas só queria saber por pura curiosidade, aprender mais coisas e novas formas de fazer também... Sobre o objetivo é checar qual a versão de um fórum (de uma determinada plataforma) com Javascript, cada plataforma tem uma estrutura HTML diferente, checando se determinado elemento existe eu sei qual a plataforma...

Comment: Acho que você não pegou um bom caso pra switch. Switch é bom pra quando voce tem um valor só, e quer fazer várias comparações neste mesmo valor. No seu exemplo você tem condições diferentes demais. E se a pessoa tiver invision e phbb3 ?

Comment: Concordo com o Bacco, este é um caso muito ruim para um switch, mas por questão de aprendizado, vou mostrar como você poderia fazer, mas para isso muita coisa terá que ser alterada... Vou reescrever seu código em uma resposta.

Comment: Era apenas para mim ter uma noção de como seria feito amigos... Neste caso não existe possibilidade dele usar mais de uma versão. Obrigado pela atenção de todos, o código funcionou perfeitamente..

Comment: A resposta ficou dependendo do if e usou o switch como mero _dispatcher_. Serve como exemplo do switch funcionando, já que o objetivo da pergunta era esse, mas note que no dia-a-dia provavelmente o switch não seria um jeito muito adequado de se resolver um problema similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A definição da função está bastante confusa. Acredito que você queira fazer o seguinte:

```
function forumversion()
{
    if (jQuery('#ipbwrapper').length) return "invision";
    if (jQuery('.bodyline').length)   return "phpbb2";
    if (jQuery('#wrap').length)       return "phpbb3";
    if (jQuery('#pun-intro').length)  return "punbb";
    return "error";
}
```

Agora no switch você deve comparar a invocação da função, não a função em si. `forumversion` nunca vai ser uma dessas strings, mas `forumversion()` vai ser. Use assim:

```
switch (forumversion()) {
case "invision":
    // Processamento aqui para esse tipo de forum
    break;
case "phpbb2":
    // Processamento aqui para esse tipo de forum
    break;
case "phpbb3":
    // Processamento aqui para esse tipo de forum
    break;
case "punbb":
    // Processamento aqui para esse tipo de forum
    break;
}
```

Se achar necessário acrescente o `defualt` ou um `case "error"` no fim as opções.

Comment: Você foi mais rápido que eu... esta escrevendo o mesmo quando vi sua resposta.

Comment: @Vieira Li seu comentário na pergunta logo depois de ter apertado e enviar. Já era tarde.